# When can a double integral be split into product of two integrals?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

When can you do the following? I tried to understand from [these](https://www.math.umd.edu/%7Emillson/teaching/STAT400fall18/slides/article17.pdf) lecture notes but I don't get whether it should be a "product function" or not.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that your formula is wrong. Nevertheless, if $g$ and $h$ are integrable on $[c,d]$ and $[a,b]$ respectively, it's always true that $$\int_a^b\int_c^d g(x)h(y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y=  \left(\int_a^b h(y)\,\mathrm d y\right)\cdot \left(\int_c^d g(x)\,\mathrm d x\right).$$  Indeed, since $h(y)$ doesn't depend on $x$, $$\int_c^d g(x)h(y)\,\mathrm dx=h(y)\underbrace{\int_c^dg(x)\,\mathrm d x}_{=:J},$$
for all $y\in [a,b]$.
Finally, since $J$ doesn't depend on $y$,
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b\int_c^d g(x)h(y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y&=\int_a^b h(y)J\,\mathrm d y\\
&=J\int_a^b h(y)\,\mathrm d y\\
&=\left(\int_c^d g(x)\,\mathrm d x\right)\cdot \left(\int_a^b h(y)\,\mathrm d y\right),
\end{align*}
as wished.

Comment: "integrable" should specify Riemann or Lebesgue.

Comment: I think there is no ambiguity at this point since in both case, this formula holds @GEdgar